# How to reset Git back to normal?

Tags: git, terminal

When I open the terminal I see this:

giorgio (master #) ~ $:

How do I exit the "master #" and go back to the normal view:

giorgio ~ $

?

Comment: Are you using git bash for windows or Linux? And why exactly do you want this?

Comment: I'm using mac. I do not understand why now it opens up with this text

Comment: If you are in a folder from a git repository it reads the `.git` directory and informs you about what branch you are on. I don't have a mac but if you remove this dir it should no longer show this text but will subsequently break your local repo for future commits.

Comment: So it basically tells you what branch you are on to make sure you don't push commits to the wrong branch by accident.

Comment: It’s defined in the environment variable `PS1`.

Comment: This will show as part of your bash prompt (PS1) whenever you are inside the directory of a git repository. It's not something you would "exit". Most developers want it, since it shows what branch you're on. You can customize your PS1 prompt, as described in the answer below, if you really want to permanently get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have something like me then maybe this helps:

open your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` ,and search for something like `export PS1='[\u@mbp \w$(__git_ps1)]\$`

`__git_ps1` is showing you the branch

You can remove/customize PS1 if you don't want.

Read more about this sort of settings here: https://gist.github.com/trey/2722934